# Jetbrains Datagrip icon cannot lock to the launcher

Tags: launcher, icons, sql

I downloaded [Jetbrains' Datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) application on Ubuntu 16.04 and started it by running it's ***datagrip.sh*** file on the terminal. When I try to select **Lock to launcher** by right clicking it's icon on the launcher, it does nothing. Can you explain me **why it does not support locking the icon to the launcher?** while other apps let me to do so.

Comment: You should be able to create a launcher from within the application itself though. In most Jetbrains apps, you can choose "_Tools_" > "_Create desktop entry / launcher_", and Datagrip should offer this too. This will create an item in the dash, which you can then drag onto the launcher.  Check this also: [Intellij launcher doesn't work on unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14424254)

Comment: I tried to find such an option in all the menu items since there is no tools menu, I don't say NO, but I will search more about it. thank you

Comment: Intellij IDEA let me to lock it's icon, actually I did not find any other app (considering the apps I already installed) that does  not let me to lock to launcher. Anyway I will try to create an icon  by using the information on link you provided. thank you

Comment: @JonasCz I followed that and it did not work.  I checked $JAVA_HOME and have a path.  There has to be something corrupt.

Answer (score 21):

Use the command described by @JonasCz. `"Tools" > "Create desktop entry / launcher"`

Then go to unity, search for DataGrip and drag it to the bar.

I don't know why pinning it doesn't work but the above worked for me. I imagine it has to do with pining the shortcut vs the running java app. The shortcut is probably a wrapper to start the main app.

Comment: Once you followed the instructions, remember that you still have to right-click the launcher icon of the launched Idea app, and choose 'lock to launcher'.